# Combining Array Binding and Associative Arrays

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, odp.net

I want to call oracle10g's stored procedure "MyStoredProcedure" from my c# .net 4 code using ODP.NET (4.112.2.0).

```
PACKAGE MyPackage AS
TYPE ids_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER(8) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure
(
   param1 IN VARCHAR2(10),
   param2 IN ids_array
);

END MyPackage;
```

I know how to use the array bind feature, so that i can insert multiple rows into a table in a single database round-trip.
I also know how to call a stored procedure which has associative array as a parameter. What i don't know is how to combine both?
I looked at http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featOraCommand.htm#i1007888 for example and sample code (but its separate examples). 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to convert the array in to comma separated string, and passed that as parameter. So inside my proc i converted my csv back to array.

Answer (score 0):

Although converting to CSV worked it is not very efficient and you are limited to 4000 characters.

To achieve what you want it would be best to use a use a forall loop

e.g.

```
PACKAGE MyPackage AS
TYPE ids_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER(8) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure
(
   param1 IN VARCHAR2(10),
   param2 IN ids_array
);
/
PACKAGE MyPackage BODY

ENDPROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure
(
   param1 IN VARCHAR2(10),
   param2 IN ids_array
) AS
BEGIN

    forall i in param2.FIRST .. param2.LAST
        INSERT INTO TABLE(col1,col2) VALUES (param1, params2(i));

END;

END MyPackage;
```

From the ODP.NET you have two parameters the first being a varchar, the second being an associative array.